# Thermal expansion coefficient of water

Tags: water

I am working through the methods section of the following paper:  [Spatial-temporal variability in surface layer deepening and lateral advection in an embayment of Lake Victoria, East Africa](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://aslo.org/lo/toc/vol_47/issue_3/0656.pdf&ei=zjc_UcG9HIyw7AalooGwDQ&usg=AFQjCNFBQ5zY0h32yJnyJMG2COsLvGiqnw&sig2=oYhtEB69Djv_Shdw0IzX6g&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU)

In the methodology section they refers to the thermal expansion coefficient of water as

$$a = 1.6 \times10^{-5} \times 9.6 \times10^{-6} \times T $$

where $T$ is the water temperature in $^\circ C$. This is valid for temperature in the range of $20-30 ^{\circ} C$. Can anyone point me to a cite-able paper that calculates the thermal expansion coefficient as a function of temperature i.e. somewhere I can find the variable for a range of temperatures not just in the range specified.

Comment: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1NYOAAAAQAAJ page 31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kate, the values you are looking for are found nicely in this table, ranging from 0 degrees to 100 degrees Celcius:  http://physchem.kfunigraz.ac.at/sm/Service/Water/H2Othermexp.htm

Below is a graph showing the coefficient of expansion plotted against Temperature in degrees Celcius.

[image]

Comment: I have also computed the coefficient in the range 20 - 30 using the formula in the paper, and it is consistent with the coefficient obtained in the same range in the linked website.  Note the website uses the formula:  a = 1.6 x10^{-5} + 9.6 x10^{-6} x T instead of a = 1.6 x10^{-5} x 9.6 x10^{-6} x T, which you have used above.