# What is the coefficient of volumetric expansion of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

What exactly is coefficient volumetric expansion? Is it $\gamma\,\Delta T$? Since water has maximum density at 4 C, is $\gamma=4\,{\rm C}^\circ$?

Comment: By "cubical expansion," do you mean an expansion in *volume*?

Comment: @KyleKanos- yes

Comment: Okay. You might be interested in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56649/thermal-expansion-coefficient-of-water) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we heat some material by a small amount $dT$ and its volume changes by $dV$, then the volume expansion coefficient $\alpha_v$ is defined by:

$$ dV = \alpha_v V dT $$

For example the volume expansion coefficient of water at 20°C is 0.000207. So if we take one cubic metre of water (so $V=1$) and heat it by 1 degree (so $dT=1$) we get:

$$ dV \approx 0.000207 \times 1 \times 1 = 0.000207 \text{ cubic metres} $$

Note the use of the *approximately equal* sign $\approx$. The equation is only exact in the limit of $dT,dV \rightarrow 0$ because the volume expansion coefficient changes with temperature.

The volume expansion coefficient of water at 4°C is actually zero. That's because 4°C is the temperature that it switches from contracting to expanding so for temperatures very close to 4°C the volume doesn't change with temperature.